# Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard issued when appliying user permisions

Tags: windows

I am new here and I am not very knowledgeable, so here is the reason of my question.
For example, I have noticed, if I need to add to a user a specific permission to a shared folder, then of course if this shared folder has a lot of subfolders and files, once we applied for the specific permission, let's say "write", then it will apply and process all this permission to all the subfolders and files under that shared folder, then, this is what happened a couple times to the other users connected to the server, see below.

While applying security permission to all subfolders and files for that specific user, then other users, start losing connection to the server and also, others that are running from their workstation an application that is in the server, they start getting kicked off the server.

The server I have, it is a Dual Xeon processor don't know right now what type it is but is one of the latest(2 processor in it), with 64 GB of ram, SAS HDD in raid 5, 8tb total space and used space 4tb, connected to gigabit switches, not all cables are 5e or 6 cat but most of them are, actually the people near the server, that even use cat 6 cables get dropped out the LAN while applying a permission for a specific user.
can anyone have a general idea, suggestions, what could be or what can I do to discover what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Use a security group, and put your user member of it and put your share security with that group.

Comment: +1 Users should *never* directly be given permissions. Always assign to groups, and then add/remove users from that group.